# How to include desktop css file only on desktop & mobile css file only on mobile?

Tags: theming

I have two different css files in my theme, one for Desktop and other for Mobile version. I want to render Desktop css file only for desktop mode and Mobile css file only for mobile mode.
Do I need to make any modification in .info of my Theme?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can do this with media queries in your info file.

Change...

```
stylesheets[all][] = css/style.css
```

to...

```
stylesheets[all and (min-width: 960px)][] = css/style.css
```

That being said, you can repeat a lot of work doing it that way. It might be easier to declare all of your styles that you know will change in a responsive.css style sheet, and use

```
@media all and (min-width: 768px) { /* all of your styles here */ }
```

At the bottom to change the values for a mobile version.